# simple question about a result of Fourier series

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I am studying the proof of this result  but i am with a problem in a part of the proof:

Result: Let $f \in L^{p}(T) = \{ h : R \rightarrow C  , \text{of period 1 such that } \int_{0}^{1}|f|^p < \infty\}$. Let $n \in N$ and consider

$$ S_nf(x) = \sum_{|j| \leq n} \hat{f}(j) e^{2 \pi i jx}.$$

Supose that exist a constant $C_p$ independent  such that $|| S_n f||_p \leq C_p || f||_p$ for all $n\in N.$

Then $S_n f \rightarrow f$ in $L^{p}(T).$

proof:Let $\epsilon >0$ . Exist $g$ a trigonometric polynomial such that $|| f - g|| < \epsilon$. Note that exists $n_0 \in N$ such that $S_n g = g  ,  \ \forall n \geq n_0$ .

then for n large
$$ || S_n f -f ||_p \leq || S_n(f-g)||_p + ||S_n g - g  ||_p + || g-f||_p < (C_p + 1)\epsilon \ \ (*)$$

I dont understand the last inequality. The only things that i am seeing is $||S_n g -g  ||_p = || g -g ||_p = 0$ and $|| g-f||_p  < \epsilon$. I am not seeing how to obtain the inequality in $(*)$. Someone can give me a hint?

thanks in advance

Observation: $\hat{f}(k) = \int_{0}^{1}f(y)e^{2 \pi i ky} \ dy , k \in Z$

Comment: Isn't it the condition? $||S_n(f-g)||\le C_p||f-g||\le C_p\epsilon$

Comment: no =\                    ------          ----------

Comment: The first inequality or the second one in $(*)$?

Comment: The first one is $||S_nf-f||=||S_nf-S_ng+S_ng-f-g+g||\le||S_n(f-g)||+||S_ng-g||+||g-f||$

Comment: it is the second one .i forget to write. sorry

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be of help. I still don't see why my first comment isn't correct... $g\in L^p$, we have that this constant exists (that is the assumption) and we get $(C_p+1)\epsilon$ on the RHS. It must be that I don't understand something. Goodluck anyway :)

Comment: The problem seems to be that, as formulated, $C_p$ is specific to $f$. One would need a reason why this same constant is also valid for all $f+g$ where $g$ is a trigonometric polynomial and $n$ is larger than the degree (highest harmonic) of $g$.

Comment: Hi @Poppy. after our discussion i  talked with my friends . and i conclude this : i dont interpreted the affirmation of the result correctly. sorry for this. i give you some points of reputation by your help . thanks four your help =)

Comment: It's ok, it's not about the points. I was just wondering what I didn't understand, trying to learn something. Thanks for your message :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large $n$, $S_{n}g=g$ because $g$ is a trigonometric polynomial. The standard orthogonality relations do the job for such a $g$ (you can think of this in $L^{2}$ in that case.) Then, by assumption $\|S_{n}(f-g)\|_{p}\le C_{p}\|(f-g)\|_{p}$, which gives the desired inequality for large $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
    \|S_{n}f-f\|_{p} & \le \|S_{n}(f-g)\|_{p}+\|S_{n}g-g\|_{p}+\|g-f\|_{p} \\
     & \le C_{p}\|(f-g)\|_{p}+0+\|f-g\|_{p} \\
     & =(C_{p}+1)\|f-g\|_{p} \\
     & \le (C_{p}+1)\epsilon.
\end{align}
$$